# Sorting one array in two arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a beginner in Java course and now I have one problem. 
I have one array with both positive and negative int.
array[]={0,5,3,6,0,-22,-6,77,-65,-34}

So now I have to create two more arrays one with positive and one with negative numbers. 
 I used for loop to sort through array but now it seems I'm doing something terribly wrong because I can only put first positive number in first place of my new positiveArray or I put the same first number in every place of my array. 
My question is how to do it to put next positive number on second place in my array and so on.

Comment: Not quite sure what you want to do, but an array has a fixed length - there is no way to know (a priori) what the ratio of positive to negative will be.  You could count the elements first then create two arrays of the correct length; then you just need to look with 3 indices and place items in the right place.

Comment: can you post the code you have already written ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some examples :

```
int[] source = new int[5];
source[0] = 4;
source[1] = 6;
source[2] = -3;
source[3] = 2;
source[4] = -1;
```

Using only int arrays :

```
// With only arrays
int positivesSize = 0;
int negativesSize = 0;

for(int value : source) {
    if (value < 0) {
        negativesSize++;
    } else {
        positivesSize++;
    }
}

int[] positivesCase1 = new int[positivesSize];
int[] negativesCase1 = new int[negativesSize];

int i = 0;
int j = 0;

for(int value : source) {
    if (value >= 0) {
        positivesCase1[i++] = value;
    } else {
        negativesCase1[j++] = value;
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(positivesCase1)); // [4, 6, 2]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(negativesCase1)); // [-3, -1]
```

Using integer lists

```
// With lists : no need to determine size of both arrays before.
List<Integer> positivesList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> negativesList = new ArrayList<>();

for(int value : source) {
    if (value >= 0) {
        positivesList.add(value);
    } else {
        negativesList.add(value);
    }
}

Integer[] positivesCase2 = positivesList.toArray(new Integer[positivesList.size()]);
Integer[] negativesCase2 = negativesList.toArray(new Integer[negativesList.size()]);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(positivesCase2)); // [4, 6, 2]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(negativesCase2)); // [-3, -1]
```

Using stream api (Java 8)

```
// With java 8

int[] positivesCase3 = Arrays.stream(source).filter(n -> n>=0).toArray();
int[] negativesCase3 = Arrays.stream(source).filter(n -> n<0).toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(positivesCase3)); // [4, 6, 2]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(negativesCase3)); // [-3, -1]
```

Comment: thank you this was very hepful

Answer (score 2):

**code**

```js
int i = 0, j = 0;

for (int a : array1){
    if (a < 0) {
        negArray[i] = a;
        i++;
    } else {
        posArray[j] = a;
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. You can also upvote this answer to enable others easily find the solution

Answer (score 1):

On for each loop make a condition if element of array is < 0 the append it to negative array else append it to positive array.

Comment: How to append an existing array? Any specific method for it?

Comment: List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();

x.add(1);

x.add(2);